# Ionic detect view in foreground or background. ionViewDidEnter, ionViewWillLeave not called

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to detect if my ionic page is in the foreground or background.

I'd like to execute some code when a alert is on top of the view or a modal opens and covers the parent view. As well as detect when they are dismissed and the view is back on top.

both ionViewDidEnter and ionViewWillLeave don't get called, is there an elegant way without handling it on each individual popup and modal?

```
  ionViewDidEnter(){
    debugger;
    //code here
  }
  
  ionViewWillLeave(){
    debugger;
    //code here
  }
```

Comment: Those are page events which are executed within a [page life cycle](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle). They do not detect if a popup or modal come to view. If you share more code, there may be a solution to your problem.

Comment: you should you `Observables` for this.

Answer (score 0):

The events ionViewDidEnter() & ionViewWillLeave() are page lifecycle events and therefore are not intended to trigger when the app moves between the foreground and background.

Cordova provides events pause & resume that are triggered when the app moves into the background & foreground respectively. An elegant way to implement this would be by using [Ionic's Platform API](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/platform/Platform/#platform) to register the events in the app.component file.

You can import Platform, provide an alias in the constructor then register the event this way :

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public plt: Platform)

this.plt.pause().then(() => {});
```